# SEO optimization for website contains sub-domain

Tags: seo

I have a website which contains sub domain, example www.example.com is main site and usa.example.com is its usa version, both site shares some common information,there will be duplicate contents so it will create seo issues , how to resolve it and what is the use of canonical tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these sites are targeted at users in different countries, there should be no SEO issue.    You do **not** want to use the canonical tag.   Log into [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) and add **each** site separately.  For the USA site, go to "Configuration" -> "Settings" and set the site targeting to "United States".  If your www site is targeted at a different country, set the correct targeting for that site too.  If your www site is supposed to be for the rest of the world, then don't set targeting for it.